# NativeScript BottomNavigation -> how to open default page on bottom navigation item tap?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have page called "Fund". I have bottom navigation with 5 tabs - "Home" / "Portfolio" and 3 others. In default behaviour all tabs has it's own navigation stack and if opened "Fund" in Home and then opened Portfolio when i return to Home "Fund" still be opened.

My goal is open default page for opened bottom navigation tab on every touch.

[Here is the sample code {N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=4Ij5yz&v=2)

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @cem-kaan https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=4Ij5yz&v=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9047) issue

> It's quite possible Frame.topmost() gets confused during tab
> transition. However, you can access a certain tab frame and call
> goBack() for it. Check this playground and let me know if it solves
> your problem:
> https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=4Ij5yz&v=7